# Changing woocommerce single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I was wondering how I would be able to change the options available from

http://peteandpedro.com/product/clean/ with just add to cart to something like

http://www.katesomerville.com/daily-deflector-waterlight-broad-spectrum-50-pa/

where you have two options available. One for one time delivery and another for auto-delivery

Answer (score 1):

1) There is an action 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' in woocommerce through you can add custom content with add to cart button.

example :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' , 'add_to_cart_content', 10 );

function add_to_cart_content(){
    echo 'Some content goes here';
}
```

Thus whatever you add ( e.g: input fields, text etc ) in the above function 'add_to_cart_content' , it will be added just with add to cart button.

The third parameter in add_action function is set to a number , which indicated the priority of the function to run. the higher number is set to, the later the function will run. So, if you want your content to be added just after the 'Add to cart' button, set the number to 40. And if you want the content before the button, set the number lower than that. You will be clear about playing with it a bit.

2) To change button text you can use 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text' like this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```